# Print all columns but first delimited by pattern, bash

Tags: bash, shell

Good day to all,

I was wondering how to print all columns but first, where each column is delimited by `;`.

Example:

```
abc; def; ghi; jkl
```

To obtain:

```
def; ghi; jkl
```

So far I have done

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; {for(i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s",$i OFS; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS}'
```

Thanks so much in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `cut`:

```
cut -f2- -d\; filename.txt
```

If your input is coming from stdin:

```
echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl" | cut -f2- -d\;
```

Comment: mmm may be I'm typing it wrong, but, when I use your example, it print me all again

Comment: Then yes, you are typing it wrong.  Are you operating on stdin or a file?

Comment: @ Sean Bright, Thanks for leading me to the right answer... I added -s to have: `cut -f2 -d\; -s`

Comment: But, it only prints me the indicated column and not from the second column forward ) :

Comment: Then you aren't putting the trailing `-` after the `-f2`

Comment: Yes, that was the reason, thanks so much for helping me. Have a good work day!

Answer (score 2):

If you know it will always be space-delimited:

```
echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl" | while read ignore line ; do echo $line ; done
```

The `while read` portion can take multiple arguments: `ignore` in this case will take the first segment, up to the first delimiter (meaning "`abc;`"), and anything not read by this is put into the rest of the arguments. In this case, it's `line`, so `line` will contain "`def; ghi; jkl`" which you print out.

```
echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl" | while read first second third ; do echo $first; echo $second; echo $third; done
```

will output

```
abc;
def;
ghi; jkl
```

**EDIT:**

If you know that it will be delimited by a different marker, you can change the `IFS` value:

```
IFS=";" ; echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl" | while read first second third ; do echo $first; echo $second; echo $third; done
```

produces:

```
abc
 def
 ghi  jkl
```

(notice the spaces before `def` and `ghi`).

Comment: good one. And to use a semicolon delimiter: `IFS=';' read ignore line <<< "$line"`

Answer (score 2):

a bash function:

```
$ myshift() {
   local IFS=';'
   set -- $1
   shift
   echo "$*"
}

$ myshift "abc; def; ghi; jkl"
 def; ghi; jkl
```

Comment: (Ab)using `IFS`... I like it.

Comment: wow, I'm learning something new today, I have seen that the use of IFS  is more practicable to extended systems

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, "abusing"? Pshaw! This is exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun with `awk` :

```
$ echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl"|awk -F "; " '{$1=""; gsub("^ +", "", $0); print}'
def; ghi; jkl
```

Using `sed` :

```
$ echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl"|sed "s/^[^;]\{1,\};\ \{1,\}//g"
def; ghi; jkl
```

As you can see that the `cut` version prints a space at the beginning of the line ;)

```
$ echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl"|cut -d";" -f2-
 def; ghi; jkl
```

So you could also try something like :

```
$ echo "abc; def; ghi; jkl"|cut -d";" -f2-|xargs
def; ghi; jkl
```

Comment: Thanks, all are good points of view and in the case of cut, to eliminate the first whitespace, is enough to indicate `-s`

Comment: @Alejandro : thanks but the `-s` only prints the lines not containing delimiters (according to the man page). This doesn't solve the space at the beginning of the line (I also tested by myself).